# Remove Server response header IIS10 from Factory configuration

Tags: header, iis-10, outsystems

I am using Outsystems tool to develop the web sites. Trying to remove server header IIS10.0 from Factory configuration. I went through the various document but I couldn't get the right solution for this.

```
   <xsl:template match="/configuration/system.webServer/httpProtocol/customHeaders">
        <xsl:copy>
            <remove name="Server"/>
               </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

Also tried

```
<xsl:template match="/configuration/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering">
        <xsl:copy>
            <add name="removeServerHeader" value="true"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

none of them are working, please suggest how to remove the Server header from Factory configuration.

[image]

Comment: First, know how you can remove that header on a test machine, https://halfblood.pro/everything-you-might-need-about-iis-server-header-58ca268547be. Then see how you translate the same steps to your transform files.

Comment: If you could access the IIS, then `select your site-> Configuration Editor-> Select system.webServer/security/requestFiltering for Section-> removeServerHeader= True`. See whether it helps. [See here](https://imgur.com/a/hxGKr57)

Comment: thanks for your reply, we don't have an IIS access. we are using factory configuration on Outsystems.

Comment: As you are using Outsystems, I would suggest you post your question at [Outsystems Forum](https://www.outsystems.com/forums/discussion/52701/remove-iis-response-header/). They could help you with the correct method that could work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these instructions:
[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

[image: Step3]